# How can I make it appear instantly on the page when I delete a product from the cart and also total price?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

```
function Basket() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState<Product[]>([]);
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(Number);

  const session = sessionStorage.getItem("user");
  let total = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      var user: User;
      const plainText = decrypt(session);
      user = JSON.parse(plainText) as User;

      userOrders(user.uid).then((res) => {
        setOrders(res.data.products);
        orders.map((item) => {
          total += item.quantity * item.price;
        });
        setTotalPrice(total);
      });

    } else {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  }, []);

  const cancelOrder = (oid: number) => {
    deleteOrder(oid);
    var user: User;
    const plainText = decrypt(session!);
    user = JSON.parse(plainText) as User;

    userOrders(user.uid).then((res) => {
      setOrders(res.data.products);
      orders.map((item) => {
        total += item.quantity * item.price;
      });
      setTotalPrice(total);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <>
        {orders.length > 0 && (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <table className="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Brand</th>
                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                    <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {orders.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <th scope="row">{item.brand}</th>
                      <td>{item.title}</td>
                      <td>{item.price}</td>
                      <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                      <td>
                        <Button
                          className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                          onClick={() => cancelOrder(item.oid)}
                        >
                          Delete
                        </Button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <h4>Total Price : {totalPrice!}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm adding and deleting products on the cart. When I delete a product from the cart I want to see the decrease in the number of products instantly on the screen, but I cannot see it. Also I print total price of products in the cart but when I add new product or delete then total price is being 0 and I need to render code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXnX9.png)

Comment: What does `deleteOrder(oid);` do? If it returns promise you had to await it.

Comment: oid is the Id of product in basket, deleteOrder is service that send request to api.

Comment: Does it return promise? You had better to add deleteOrder code

Comment: export const deleteOrder = (oid:number) =>{
    return config.get('order/delete/'+oid)
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in cancelOrder metod.

Firstly, since you call an api in deleteOrder method, and it returns promise, you need to use await (or then ).

Also since state update is asynchronous, you can't access the updated values immediately, it will return previous state.

So cancelOrder method should be something like this:

```
const cancelOrder = async (oid: number) => {

  await deleteOrder(oid);
  var user: User;
  const plainText = decrypt(session!);
  user = JSON.parse(plainText) as User;

  const res = await userOrders(user.uid);
  setOrders(res.data.products);
    
  res.data.products.map((item) => {
      total += item.quantity * item.price;
  });

  setTotalPrice(total);
};
```